# Which tense should I use?

Tags: tense

If someone made  the same mistake two times . And I found out after a few days. I should say:

> (1) It **was** the second time you did it, so I won't forgive you this time

or

> (2) It **is** the second time you did it, so I won't forgive you this time

Comment: Basically, you're asking if you need "the" in front of "second time"?  In most cases an article is required before nouns in English.  Whether you use "the" or something else depends on context.  In this case "the" is required.

Comment: @Andrew I think the OP is asking is it "was" or "is" ?

Comment: @Mrt , Aha right I see it now.

Comment: I would go for #1. And would replace _did_ with _made_.

Comment: I'd say; "that is the second time you've done that, so I won't forgive you" it still has the implication that it was done in the past, but that I've found out just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can be correct, but there is a slight difference in nuance. Using *was* is correct, since the second time WAS in the past.

However, if you can imagine the speaker in the present mentally reviewing a series of mistakes, then *is* becomes more appropriate. Using *is*, I think, from personal experience, is more of a reprimand and can imply that there is a series of mistakes going on here.

Also, use of *is* agrees with *this*, which implies present tense.

I would use present tense.

N.B. Usually we say *twice* in English, instead of *two times*.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Vekzhivi. It does help a lot.